# Firebase Auth emulator sometimes return Auth object from real Auth in the net

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

firebase-tools: 9.23.1

Platform:
macOS
Flutter
Mobile application
Real Android device.

While running Flutter mobile application  with Firebase emulators (FireStore, Auth, Functions, Storage, Hosting), I have noticed that sometimes the emulator returns Auth data from the real Auth and not from the emulator Auth.  This does not happen often. I spent so many hours trying to debug this.  Unfortunately, it was not easy to reproduce.

In firebase.json I have the following config:

```
  "emulators": {
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 4000
    },
    "functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "hosting": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5002
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8085
    },
    "auth": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "storage": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9199
    }
  },
```

In my Flutter mobile App, I have the following code to use the emulators:

```
Future<void> _useEmulators() async {
  final ip = "192.168.1.133";
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator(ip, 9199);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator(ip, 8080, sslEnabled: false);
  FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-east4')
      .useFunctionsEmulator(ip, 5001);
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(ip, 9099);
}

void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await _useEmulators();

    return runApp(child: const App());
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I found out that when you open app as signed in user (user have been signed in during previous session) auth emulator is not getting set correctly. When Auth emulator is set I see warning at the bottom of my app. But in this case there is no warning and auth is not working

Comment: I am not running into this problem anymore.  Make sure you install the latest firebase cli.  Firebase team is really good at keeping it up to date.